# Removing scientific notation in ggstatsplot (R)

Tags: r, scientific-notation, ggstatsplot

I am trying to remove scientific notation that appears above a graph generated by ggstatsplot. The p value reported there (together with the value of the test statistic, etc.) is given in scientific notation, which I would like to turn off. Scientific notation is also used for group comparisons and I would like to turn it off too. What should I do?

Comment: Could you please share the code you have tried?

Comment: I tried this to get the results (includng the graphs) ggbetweenstats(data=data, x=V1, y=V53, type="np"). I also tried this to turn off scientific notation: options(scipen=999) and I ran that command before running the command used to generate the graphs. That did not help though.

Comment: And could you please share some reproducible data in your question using `dput(data)`?

Comment: `ggstatsplot` is designed to add all these notations - you may be better off building up from standard `ggplot`s rather than trying to start from the most complex position. If you are sticking with it, it's worth looking into the `theme_ggstatsplot()` theme which is applied as a default to all the plots.

Answer (score 0):

```
options(scipen=999) 
ggbetweenstats(data=data, x=V1, y=V53, type="np"). 
      

structure(list(V1 = c("Version 1", "Version 1", "Version 1", 
    "Version 1", "Version 1", "Version 1", "Version 1", "Version 1"
    ), V2 = c(659L, 665L, 635L, 944L, 1115L, 1146L, 1192L, 1414L), 
        V3 = c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No"
        ), V4 = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), 
        V5 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"
        ), V6 = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), 
        V7 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes"
        ), V8 = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes"
        ), V9 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
        "Yes"), V10 = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
        "No"), V11 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
        "No"), V12 = c("No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", 
        "Yes"), V13 = c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
        "Yes", "No"), V14 = c("No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
        "No", "Yes"), V15 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), V16 = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
        "No", "No", "Yes"), V17 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
        "Yes", "Yes", "No"), V18 = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
        "No", "No", "Yes"), V19 = c("No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
        "No", "No", "Yes"), V20 = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
        "No", "No", "No"), V21 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), V22 = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
        "No", "No", "No"), V23 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), V24 = c("No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", 
        "Yes", "No", "No"), V25 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
        "Yes", "Yes", "No"), V26 = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
        "No", "No", "Yes"), V27 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), V28 = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
        "No", "No", "No"), V29 = c("Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
        "Yes", "Yes", "No"), V30 = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
        "No", "No", "Yes"), V31 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), V32 = c("No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", 
        "No", "No", "No"), V33 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), V34 = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
        "No", "No", "Yes"), V35 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), V36 = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
        "No", "No", "No"), V37 = c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), V38 = c("No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
        "No", "Yes", "No"), V39 = c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
        "No", "Yes", "Yes"), V40 = c("No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
        "Yes", "No", "Yes"), V41 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
        "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No"), V42 = c("No", "No", "No", "No", 
        "No", "Yes", "No", "No"), V43 = c("No", "No", "No", "Yes", 
        "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No"), V44 = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", 
        "No", "No", "No", "No"), V45 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
        "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes"), V46 = c("No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
        "No", "Yes", "No", "No"), V47 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), V48 = c("No", "Yes", "No", "No", 
        "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes"), V49 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
        "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), V50 = c("No", "No", "No", "No", 
        "No", "No", "Yes", "No"), V51 = c("No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No"), V52 = c("Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", 
        "No", "No", "No", "No"), V53 = c(22L, 18L, 23L, 23L, 21L, 
        18L, 24L, 16L), V54 = c(3L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 9L), 
        V55 = c(2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 10L), V56 = c(23L, 20L, 
        22L, 20L, 23L, 18L, 23L, 15L)), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```